# How to get name of MAX and MIN values in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have pig code to get max and min values. I can show them but without name of what is max and min

in the code you can see I wrote data.KEY but this one will print all names

```html
film = LOAD './film.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS 
     (film_id:int,title:chararray,description:chararray,release_year:int,language_id:int,rental_duration:int,
     rental_rate:int,length:float,replacement_cost:float,rating:chararray,special_features:chararray);
film_category = LOAD './film_category.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (film_id:int , category_id:int);
category = LOAD './category.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (category_id:int , name:chararray);

result1 = JOIN film BY film_id , film_category BY film_id;
result2 = JOIN result1 BY film_category::category_id , category BY category_id;

result3 =  foreach (GROUP result2 BY category::name) generate group as KEY , AVG(result2.length) as avg_value;
data = ORDER result3 BY KEY ASC;
grouped = GROUP data All;

max = foreach grouped generate data.KEY as name1, MAX(data.avg_value) as max_value;
min = foreach grouped generate data.KEY as name2, MIN(data.avg_value) as min_value;

values = foreach grouped GENERATE max.name1, max.max_value  , min.name2, min.min_value;

DUMP values;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating 'values' relation by using grouped which will generate all names since you are grouping by all.After grouping for max, order by desc and get the top row.Similarly for min,order by asc and get the top row.

```
max_min = foreach grouped {
            desc_order = order data by avg_value DESC;
            asc_order = order data by avg_value ASC;
            desc_limit = limit desc_order 1;
            asc_limit = limit asc_order 1;
            generate flatten(desc_limit),flatten(asc_limit);
}
DUMP max_min;
```

Comment: thank you for response. but your code printed all names. 
({(Travel),(Sports),(Sci-Fi),(New),(Music),(Horror),(Games),(Foreign),(Family),(Drama),(Documentary),(Comedy),(Classics),(Children),(Animation),(Action)},128.2027027027027,108.19672131147541). what I want is name of max with max value and name of min with min value

Comment: thank you it is working. However, you need to delete "data" in 2nd and 3rd lines before avg_value

Comment: @AliAl-ali Cool.